# Is it a bug in the UNIX cut command that when selecting a specific field with a line with no delimiters, it returns the whole line?

Tags: cut, gnu-coreutils

I found this behavior of coreutils utility `cut` a bit weird

```
echo "
one,line1
two,line2
three
four,line4
" | cut -d ',' -f1
```

, got expected result:

```
one
two
three
four
```

But:

```
echo "
one,line1
two,line2
three
four,line4
" | cut -d ',' -f2
```

, gives outputs:

```
line1
line2
three
line4
```

I would expect 3rd line to be empty. Are my expectations wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. From the manpage for the `-f` option:

> Select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified

Since your third line has no delimiter, then it prints the whole line.

If you add `-s`, you will get this output:

```
line1
line2
line4
```

---

If you add a delimiter to your third line at the end, like this

```
echo "
one,line1
two,line2
three,
four,line4
" | cut -d ',' -f2
```

Then you will get this:

```
line1
line2

line4
```

Comment: Fair point. Reading documentation always helps. Thanks!